# What is the Euler characteristic of a tensor power of the dualizing sheaf of a stable curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a stable curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $\omega_X$ be its dualizing sheaf.

How can we calculate the Euler characteristics $\chi(\omega_X^{\otimes m})$?

A paper I'm reading claims that $\chi(\omega_X^{\otimes 2}) = 3g'-3$, but they annoyingly never define $g'$. From context, I would guess that $g' := \dim H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ (ie, the arithmetic genus), but I'm not sure. Could this be correct?

Comment: What is the paper?

Comment: @Nefertiti This is "Champs de Hurwitz" by Bertin-Romagny - near the bottom of page 55. You can find the paper here: https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/matthieu.romagny/articles/champs_de_Hurwitz.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g'$ is the genus of $X$, which is $H^1(X, \mathscr O_X)$ or (equivalently, for smooth curves), $H^0(X, \omega_X)$.

Recall one formulation of Riemann-Roch: Let $D$ be a divisor. Then
$$
\chi(\mathscr O(D)) = \deg D -g + 1.
$$
See Hartshorne, the chapter on Riemann-Roch. He also proves that the degree of the canonical divisor is $2g-2$. Since $\omega_X^{\otimes m}$ has associated divisor class $mK_X$, where $K_X$ is the divisor class of $\omega_X$, it follows by Riemann-Roch that
$$
\chi(\omega_X^{\otimes m}) = \chi(\mathscr O(mK_X) = m (2g-2)-g+1.
$$

Putting $m=2$, we find that
$$
\chi(\omega_X^{\otimes 2}) = \chi(\mathscr O(2K_X) = 2 (2g-2)-g+1 = 3g-3.
$$

Comment: It looks like Hartshorne's chapter on Riemann-Roch assumes the curve is smooth, right? Does what you wrote still work for stable curves?

Also I think $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = H^0(X,\omega_X)$ for all curves - I don't think smoothness is needed for that equality.

Comment: Ah, I see it's Exercise 1.9 in that chapter. That answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Nesos At least some condition is needed for $H^1(X, \mathscr O_X)=H^0(X,\omega_X)$. If $X$ is a cusp, then $h^0(X,\omega_X)=2$, while $h^1(X,\mathscr O_X)=1$.

Comment: @Nesos (though I guess the cusp is not stable, so the counterexample is not relevant to your case)

Comment: So my understanding is that the identification $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = H^0(X,\omega_X)$ follows from the definition of the dualizing sheaf of any flat projective local complete intersection morphism of relative dimension 1. (e.g. Qing Liu's book Theorem 4.32 in Section 6.4). Aren't all projective integral schemes of dimension 1 over $k$ local complete intersections? Are you saying that cuspidal curves aren't local complete intersections?